# Variance of probability distributions described by kinked functions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If I have the probability distribution $f(x) = \begin{cases}x & 0 < x < 1 \\ 2-x & 1 < x < 2 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$,

how do I calculate $E(X)$, and $E(X^2)$, and therefore $VAR(X)$?

I understand that $E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty xf(x)~dx$, and $E(X^2)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2f(x)~dx$, but don't know how to apply this given that the function takes different forms over $(0,1)$ and $(1,2)$.

Comment: Each integral is actually restricted to $(0,2)$ and can be decomposed as $$\int_0^1+\int_1^2$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $$E(X)=\int_0^2 xf(x) dx= \int_0^1 x\cdot x dx+\int_1^2 x\cdot (2-x) dx$$
   $$= \int_0^1 x^2 dx+\int_1^2 (2x-x^2) dx$$
   $$=\frac{1}{3}+\big[x^2-\frac{x^3}{3}\big]^2_1$$
   $$=\frac{1}{3}+\big[4-1-\frac{8}{3}+\frac{1}{3}\big]$$
   $$=1$$
2. $$E(X^2)=\int_0^2 x^2f(x) dx= \int_0^1 x^2\cdot x dx+\int_1^2 x^2\cdot (2-x) dx$$
   $$= \int_0^1 x^3 dx+\int_1^2 (2x^2-x^3) dx$$
3. $$V(X)=E(X^2)-\big[E(X)\big]^2$$

It is easy to compute.